# Locating and obtaining a sequence from a huge text file which includes other information

Tags: perl

I am given 2 text files of P3DB format (first one called "sites" has protein IDs, second one called "proteins" which has sequences of the corresponding protein IDs). I have to convert these two into a single PhosphoSitePlus text file using Perl script.

I have figured out how to convert most of the information. Now I have to find the sequence and the organism name in "proteins" file. I have a certain protein ID number (for example, 2329) from the "sites" file. Now I have to search for this number in the "proteins" file. I find this number, but under it is a lot of unnecessary data and under that somewhere is the sequence followed by the organism name. I'm not sure how to obtain the sequence because I don't know when it will start or stop.

There is a pattern where all of the sequences start with a tab space and an "M". However, the last residue can be anything. Also, the organism name might start right after the sequence (without a space) or after a number of spaces following the sequence.

I want to be able to save the complete sequence that corresponds to the protein ID to be able to find a single residue within that sequence at a given position(number). Or to be able to find that one residue without having to first save the sequence.

Here is roughly what I have come up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $filename2 = $ARGV[1];

open AFILE, "$filename"; #open file - sites file 
open BFILE, "$filename2"; #open second file - proteins file 
open NEWFILE, ">PhosphoSitePlus.txt"; #make a new file to save

my @chunks = ();
my @blines = <BFILE>;
my $sequence;
my $res;
my $organism;
my $PID;
my $ACC;
my $Psite;

print NEWFILE "Accession        Modified Residue        Site Group ID   Organism        Sequence";

while (defined(my $line = <AFILE>)) { #iterate through lines of the _sites file
    my @chunks = split ' ', $line; #split columns into an array
    next if ( $chunks[0] =~  /P3DB/ ); #skip the first line (the headers)
    $PID = $chunks[0]; #save the Protein ID
    $ACC = $chunks[1]; #save the Accession number
    $Psite = $chunks[3]; #save the site that is phosphorylated

    foreach (0 .. $#blines){ #iterate through p3db_proteins

        my @b = split ' ', $blines[$_]; #split columns of lines into array
        if ($b[0] =~/^$PID$/){  #if the first column is equal to the protein ID the sequence is under
            next if ($blines[$_] !~ /^\s+M\w{20,}$/);
            if ( $blines[$_] =~ /^\tM\w{20,}$/ ){ #the start of the sequence(tab and an M, followed by 20 or more characters?)
                #save this sequence, or find the residue that is at the position of $Psite
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some examples of the sequences in the proteins file(2329 and 2330 are the protein ID, and under that starting with M are the sequences and organism names).

```
2329    EMBL:AAM13013.1;EMBL:AAM65937.1;EMBL:AAP13391.1;EMBL:AEC10514.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT2G45140;TAIR:At2g45140;TAIR:AT2G45140.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT2G45140.1;TAIR:AT2G45140.1;PIR:H84886;IPI:IPI00531520.1;Refseq:NM_130077.2;Refseq:NP_182039.1;Swissport:Q9SHC8.1;UniParc:UPI00000A0803;Swissport:VAP12_ARATH    plant VAP homolog 12    MSNELLTIDPVDLQFPFELKKQISCSLYLGNKTDNYVAFKVKTTNPKKYCVRPNTGVVHPRSSSEVLVTMQAQKEAPADLQCKDKFLLQCVVASPGATPKDVTHEMFSKEAGHRVEETKLRVVYVAPPRPPSPVREGSEEGSSPRASVSDNGNASDFTAAPRFSADRVDAQDNSSEARALVTKLTEEKNSAVQLNNRLQQELDQLRRESKRSKSGGIPFMYVLLVGLIGLILGYIMKRT Arabidopsis thaliana    19376835;19253305;19245862;18463617;17651370;17317660;15308754
2330    EMBL:AEE76598.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT3G22180;TAIR:At3g22180;TAIR:AT3G22180.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT3G22180.1;TAIR:AT3G22180.1;EMBL:BAB03066.1;IPI:IPI00547221.2;Refseq:NM_113115.3;Refseq:NP_188857.1;Swissport:Q9LIE4.2;UniParc:UPI00001634CF;Swissport:ZDHC8_ARATH   DHHC-type zinc finger family protein    MVRKHGWQLPAHTLQVIAITVFCLLVVAFYAFFAPFVGGRIWEYVLIGVYSPVAILVFVLYVRCTAINPADPRIMSIFDTGVNGDGMVRGLSRNYDETGSQLQASPSVVSRSSTVAGNSSVKGSVEDAQRVESVSRRSCYNPLAVFCYVFVVEDCRKKEGPAEEQGNSEEALFCTLCNCEVRKFSKHCRSCDKCVDCFDHHCKWLNNCVGRKNYVTFVSLMSASLLWLIIEAAVGIAVIVRVFVNKQTMETEIVNRLGNSFSRAPLAAVVGLCTAVAIFACFPLGELLFFHMLLIKKGITTYEYVVAMRAMSEAPDGASVDEEIQNVLYSPTGSATTGFSGGSSLGLPYRGVWCTPPRVFDNQDEVIPHLDPCMVPSTVDPDAPGSEKGTKALKRPVKRNAWKLAKLDPNEAARAAARARASSSVLRPIDNRHLPDNDLSSIGTVSIISSVSTDANVAASKEIRNNDLRSSLSRNSFAPSQGSRDEYDTGSHGMSNLSSPSHVHESVTLAPLPQNPTIVGNRFTATSHHMHSTFDDKVLHRGNDADPLFLFAPATSHLRDVRKTSVVWDPEAGRYVSAPVTTTSEVRNRLLNPSSQTASTQNPRPILPAHDSSSGSSALRDPLPLHQAERRLTYTGDSIFYGGPLINIPTRDTPRSGRGLVRDVQDRLASTVHRDARIRRDSTSNQLPVFAPGGLGANSQTGSNIK  Arabidopsis thaliana    17317660
```

Comment: Please would you edit your question so that it shows the data properly? You have used right angle brackets `>` which is intended for quoting sections of prose. It reduces multiple spaces to single ones and runs the lines together without a break as well as using a variable-width font, so it is hard to see what the original data looks like. You can mark a piece of code or data by indenting every line of the block by four spaces. It may be simpler if you paste the text in directly from your file, select it, and press `CTRL-K`. That will indent the whole block for you.

Comment: I have edited the data using CTRL-K. Thanks.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for the `CTRL-K` trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `^` which matches the beginning of the line and `$` which matches to the end of line, implying the only thing on that line is sequence you're looking for starting with an M.

But if your data is as shown, that is not the case.

Also if your file is as big as you say, I suggest not slurping the entire file into memory, and doing it line by line.

Below regex should do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $id = 2329;
my @info;
while(my $line = <DATA>){
    if($line =~ /(2329|2330)/){
        push @info, $line =~ /\s+(M\w+)/;
    }
}

print Dumper @info;

__DATA__
2329    EMBL:AAM13013.1;EMBL:AAM65937.1;EMBL:AAP13391.1;EMBL:AEC10514.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT2G45140;TAIR:At2g45140;TAIR:AT2G45140.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT2G45140.1;TAIR:AT2G45140.1;PIR:H84886;IPI:IPI00531520.1;Refseq:NM_130077.2;Refseq:NP_182039.1;Swissport:Q9SHC8.1;UniParc:UPI00000A0803;Swissport:VAP12_ARATH    plant VAP homolog 12    MSNELLTIDPVDLQFPFELKKQISCSLYLGNKTDNYVAFKVKTTNPKKYCVRPNTGVVHPRSSSEVLVTMQAQKEAPADLQCKDKFLLQCVVASPGATPKDVTHEMFSKEAGHRVEETKLRVVYVAPPRPPSPVREGSEEGSSPRASVSDNGNASDFTAAPRFSADRVDAQDNSSEARALVTKLTEEKNSAVQLNNRLQQELDQLRRESKRSKSGGIPFMYVLLVGLIGLILGYIMKRT Arabidopsis thaliana    19376835;19253305;19245862;18463617;17651370;17317660;15308754
2330    EMBL:AEE76598.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT3G22180;TAIR:At3g22180;TAIR:AT3G22180.1;Ensembl Genomes:AT3G22180.1;TAIR:AT3G22180.1;EMBL:BAB03066.1;IPI:IPI00547221.2;Refseq:NM_113115.3;Refseq:NP_188857.1;Swissport:Q9LIE4.2;UniParc:UPI00001634CF;Swissport:ZDHC8_ARATH   DHHC-type zinc finger family protein    MVRKHGWQLPAHTLQVIAITVFCLLVVAFYAFFAPFVGGRIWEYVLIGVYSPVAILVFVLYVRCTAINPADPRIMSIFDTGVNGDGMVRGLSRNYDETGSQLQASPSVVSRSSTVAGNSSVKGSVEDAQRVESVSRRSCYNPLAVFCYVFVVEDCRKKEGPAEEQGNSEEALFCTLCNCEVRKFSKHCRSCDKCVDCFDHHCKWLNNCVGRKNYVTFVSLMSASLLWLIIEAAVGIAVIVRVFVNKQTMETEIVNRLGNSFSRAPLAAVVGLCTAVAIFACFPLGELLFFHMLLIKKGITTYEYVVAMRAMSEAPDGASVDEEIQNVLYSPTGSATTGFSGGSSLGLPYRGVWCTPPRVFDNQDEVIPHLDPCMVPSTVDPDAPGSEKGTKALKRPVKRNAWKLAKLDPNEAARAAARARASSSVLRPIDNRHLPDNDLSSIGTVSIISSVSTDANVAASKEIRNNDLRSSLSRNSFAPSQGSRDEYDTGSHGMSNLSSPSHVHESVTLAPLPQNPTIVGNRFTATSHHMHSTFDDKVLHRGNDADPLFLFAPATSHLRDVRKTSVVWDPEAGRYVSAPVTTTSEVRNRLLNPSSQTASTQNPRPILPAHDSSSGSSALRDPLPLHQAERRLTYTGDSIFYGGPLINIPTRDTPRSGRGLVRDVQDRLASTVHRDARIRRDSTSNQLPVFAPGGLGANSQTGSNIK  Arabidopsis thaliana    17317660
```

Also, on your line `while(defined(my $line = <AFILE>))` perl already knows what you mean here and you do not need to include the defined part. If it does not receive data / or gets to the end of file, $line will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I understand something of what you want.

The small amount of data you have shown seems to be fairly well behaved in that both lines have six tab-separated fields. The ID is the first field and the sequence is the fourth. You also mention the organism name, which I think is the fifth field, but you don't make it clear whether you're interested in this value.

Since you say your dataset is large, to get any sort of performance out of this you need to build a *hash* from the proteins file, with the protein ID as the key and the sequence and organism name as the value.

Thereafter you can just look up the data for a given protein ID instead of searching through the file.

This short program shows an example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %proteins;

open my $proteins_fh, '<', 'proteins.pdb' or die $!;

while (<$proteins_fh>) {
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  my ($pid, $sequence) = @fields[0, 3];
  $proteins{$pid} = $sequence;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%proteins;
```

**output**

```
{
  2329 => [
            "MSNELLTIDPVDLQFPFELKKQISCSLYLGNKTDNYVAFKVKTTNPKKYCVRPNTGVVHPRSSSEVLVTMQAQKEAPADLQCKDKFLLQCVVASPGATPKDVTHEMFSKEAGHRVEETKLRVVYVAPPRPPSPVREGSEEGSSPRASVSDNGNASDFTAAPRFSADRVDAQDNSSEARALVTKLTEEKNSAVQLNNRLQQELDQLRRESKRSKSGGIPFMYVLLVGLIGLILGYIMKRT",
            "Arabidopsis thaliana",
          ],
  2330 => [
            "MVRKHGWQLPAHTLQVIAITVFCLLVVAFYAFFAPFVGGRIWEYVLIGVYSPVAILVFVLYVRCTAINPADPRIMSIFDTGVNGDGMVRGLSRNYDETGSQLQASPSVVSRSSTVAGNSSVKGSVEDAQRVESVSRRSCYNPLAVFCYVFVVEDCRKKEGPAEEQGNSEEALFCTLCNCEVRKFSKHCRSCDKCVDCFDHHCKWLNNCVGRKNYVTFVSLMSASLLWLIIEAAVGIAVIVRVFVNKQTMETEIVNRLGNSFSRAPLAAVVGLCTAVAIFACFPLGELLFFHMLLIKKGITTYEYVVAMRAMSEAPDGASVDEEIQNVLYSPTGSATTGFSGGSSLGLPYRGVWCTPPRVFDNQDEVIPHLDPCMVPSTVDPDAPGSEKGTKALKRPVKRNAWKLAKLDPNEAARAAARARASSSVLRPIDNRHLPDNDLSSIGTVSIISSVSTDANVAASKEIRNNDLRSSLSRNSFAPSQGSRDEYDTGSHGMSNLSSPSHVHESVTLAPLPQNPTIVGNRFTATSHHMHSTFDDKVLHRGNDADPLFLFAPATSHLRDVRKTSVVWDPEAGRYVSAPVTTTSEVRNRLLNPSSQTASTQNPRPILPAHDSSSGSSALRDPLPLHQAERRLTYTGDSIFYGGPLINIPTRDTPRSGRGLVRDVQDRLASTVHRDARIRRDSTSNQLPVFAPGGLGANSQTGSNIK",
            "Arabidopsis thaliana",
          ],
}
```

Thereafter, you can look up the sequence and organism name directly from the hash without having to search for it. The read loop for your `sites` file becomes just this.

```
while (<$sites_fh>) {

  my @chunks = split /\t/;
  next if $chunks[0] =~ /P3DB/;

  my ($pid, $acc, $psite) = $chunks[0, 1, 3];

  my $sequence = $proteins{$pid}[0];
  my $name     = $proteins{$pid}[1];

  # Use $sequence and $name somehow

}
```

Note that I've changed your identifiers to lower case. People familiar with Perl will thank you if you leave upper case letters for global variables like package names.

I have also changed your file handle `AFILE` to a lexical `$sites_fh`, so you will need to change your open statement to something like

```
open my $sites_fh, '<', 'sites.pdb' or die $!;
```

I hope this helps.